# Datetime force milliseconds

Tags: c#, datetime, milliseconds

I have a WCF service that returns data as JSON. I have a problem where datetime cuts milliseconds when it's 00.

How can I force datetime to not cut the milliseconds? I want to return it as a `DateTime` and not a `string`.

```
[
  {
    "date": "2013-04-09T09:21:32",
    "route_id": 60256,
    "route_name": "Karlstad Malung",
    "type": "Comment"
  },
  {
    "date": "2013-04-09T09:20:58.91",
    "route_id": 60256,
    "route_name": "Test",
    "type": "Comment"
  },
```

Comment: WCF pipeline is heavily customisable, I'd guess you want to use your own JSON serializer, or report a bug in Microsoft's/the one you are using, if you believe it's not standards-compliant.  Or if it is, make your calling code standards-compliant!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the ".f" formatting modifier:

```
DateTime dateValue = new DateTime(2008, 7, 16, 8, 32, 45, 0);
Console.WriteLine("{0} seconds", dateValue.ToString("s.f"));
Console.WriteLine("{0} seconds", dateValue.ToString("s.ff"));
Console.WriteLine("{0} seconds", dateValue.ToString("s.ffff"));
// The example displays the following output to the console: 
//    45.0 seconds 
//    45.00 seconds 
//    45.0000 seconds
```

The second step would be to modify the WCF serializer to use this `DateTime` format.